# Save all content of NSMutableArray in a file iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, writetofile

I have sqlite db and export some result with query

```
sqlite3 *MyDB;
const char *dbpath = [StringPathDB UTF8String]; // Convert NSString to UTF-8
NSString *querySQL = @"select * from chat order by id desc limit 20";



if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &MyDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    const char *sql = [querySQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *searchStatement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(MyDB, sql, -1, &searchStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(searchStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *nickname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 0)];
            NSString *time = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 1)];
            NSString *text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 2)];
```

Then I put all in NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[list addObject:nickname];
[list addObject:time];
[list addObject:text];
```

When I try to save al in file with this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < [list count]; i++) {

                    NSLog(@"%@",list);
                   [list writeToFile:filePATH atomically:YES];
                   break;
                }
```

It stamps correctly in NSLog but in file saves only the last record not all array.
Please help me!

Comment: What is `filePATH`? How are you creating it?

Comment: Is everything in `list` as verified by `NSLog()`?

Comment: You'd need to actually accumulate all the records in order to write them all.  Your list will only include one record.  (And if you write multiple records there will be nothing to separate them.  You need to re-think what you're trying to do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the `NSMutableArray` once and make all additions to it.

```
NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while (sqlite3_step(searchStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    NSString *nickname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 0)];
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 1)];
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 2)];
    [list addObject:nickname];
    [list addObject:time];
    [list addObject:text];
    ...
}
[list writeToFile:filePATH atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks... Your solution works fine! Can I write the file where there are the 3 elements in one row? Now the result is one element for row
nickname 1
time 1
text 1
nickname 2
time 2
text 2
...

I wanna: 
nickname 1 time 1 text 1
nickname 2 time 2 text 2 
....

It is possible?

Comment: You could write code to create a new `NSMutableArray`, access the current array in the order you want and add the items to the new array. But the array as is is probable the best arraignment, just access as needed.

Comment: Ask in another question. Also there are probably larger design issues that involve how this array will be used.